# How to use trainbr training function

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to use trainbr training function for my neural network character recognition project. How to choose the parameters and number of iterations for this function? Also how to divide data for training,validation and testing? I have gone through the nn toolbox documentation. But i am struggling to understand the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In neural-network, the parameter the number of the  layers(layer_size) and the number of neurons(neuron_size)  per each layer，the model complexity is increased as the layer_size & neuronz_size increase,since it will endow the model the ability to fit more complex functions, but as the complexity of the model increase, it is easy being lead to overfitting(which means you get a low error rate in train data ,but get a high error rate in validation data and test data).

the iterations should related to the gradient you are expecting , since neural-network is usually optimize with gradient-descending method , usually we would stop the iteration when the gradient reach a minimum value( eg 1e-4), but it depends, I suggest you check the gradient instead of care too much about iterations ,since the iteration number is depend on the train data.

I suggest choose the ratio of  train:validation：test to be 6:3:1, but it depend the sample num you got ,usually , I set the test sample num to 0,just using train&validation data set.

Comment: Can you explain about the parameters in trainbr function?

Comment: @Anu trainbr use Levenberg-Marquardt optimization, you should  read something about it(http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/notes/lm.pdf ) for the mu, and  net.trainParam.min_grad is the grad you should care about